# Next run time for cloudwatch rate expression

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have scheduled Fixed rate of 2 days for an event rule. Where can I find the next run time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It counts from the date and time you created the CloudWatch event. If your rate expression is `rate(1 day)` and you created the event at 22:00:00 UTC, then it will run at that time the next day. A rate expression for 2 days will fire two days later at the same time. And similarly a rate expression at 5 minutes will fire every five minutes *beginning at the time the CloudWatch event was created*.

To verify this, you can create a Lambda function that uploads an object to an S3 bucket, create a CloudWatch event for it, making note of the time you created it, and observe that when the event fires, the modification date of the object is that many days/minutes/hours from the time you created the event.